# Create Notes(content documents) preventing the edit and Delete on notes

Tags: trigger, contentdocument

i need an option to create a note preventing the edit and delete on notes for a particular custom object.
i wrote a below trigger .. but it is restricting to create a note also.

```
trigger NoteTrigger on ContentDocument(before delete, before update) {

    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult inv = Claim__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    String invKeyPrefix = inv.getKeyPrefix();

    List < Id > contentDocId = new List < Id > ();
    Map < Id, Id > contDocLinkedMap = new Map < Id, Id > ();

    if (trigger.IsDelete || trigger.IsUpdate) {
        for (ContentDocument con: Trigger.old) {
            contentDocId.add(con.Id);
        }
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl: [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: contentDocId]) {
            contDocLinkedMap.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, cdl.LinkedEntityId);
            System.debug('map ' + contDocLinkedMap);
        }

        for (ContentDocument cdoc: Trigger.new == null ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new) {
            //contDocLinkedMap.get(cdoc.Id) will give the LinkedEntityId
            if (invKeyPrefix == String.valueOf(contDocLinkedMap.get(cdoc.Id)).left(3) && cdoc.FileType == 'SNOTE') {
                cdoc.adderror('Notes could not be Edited or deleted .');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to indent and format your code to help readers understand its logical structure.

Answer (score 2):

`ContentDocument` acts, in the Content model, as the parent of one or more `ContentVersion` records, which represent the versions of the underlying body content (here, the note itself). As the parent, `ContentDocument` is inserted first, followed by `ContentVersion`, when a record is created.

Fields on the [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocument.htm) may be altered by the insertion of a `ContentVersion`, including the first one created upon the initial addition of a Note. (`LatestPublishedVersionId` and `ContentSize`, for example, one might expect to update - I don't know the exact underlying mechanics).

As a result an `update` trigger on `ContentDocument` will be fired during the initial insertion of a Note.

You'll probably have to do some experimenting with heuristics to determine whether the `update` event you're processing for any specific `ContentDocument` is actually the initial insert. Perhaps you could check if the old value of `LatestPublishedVersionId` is `null`? I'm not actually certain what logic will be needed.

As an additional note, your code currently assumes that each `ContentDocument` is associated with exactly one `ContentDocumentLink`, and that assumption is not accurate.

Comment: i wrote a trigger on contentversion object for before update , but need to know how restrict this only one specific custom object. any help please. 
trigger ContentVersion_PreventUpdate on ContentVersion (before update) 
{ 
for ( ContentVersion oldCv : Trigger.old ) 
{ ContentVersion newCv = Trigger.newMap.get(oldCv.Id); 
if ( (oldCv.Title != newCv.Title || oldCv.Description != newCv.Description) && oldCv.FileType='SNOTE') 
{ newCv.addError('You do not have permission to edit this record.'); 
} } }

Comment: @Madhu If you have a new question, please open a new post. You'll need to provide more detail about what you're asking in that post; I am not sure how to answer based on what you said.