# restrict user to edit the notes using the trigger on ContentVersion

Tags: trigger, contentversion

### Please help me with this.

```
trigger ContentVersion_PreventUpdate on ContentVersion (before update) 
{
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult inv = 
customobject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
String invKeyPrefix = inv.getKeyPrefix();

 System.debug('Inv ' +invKeyPrefix);

 List<Id> contentDocId = new List<Id>();
 Map<Id, Id> contDocLinkedMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

 for ( ContentVersion oldCv : Trigger.old )
  {
  system.debug(oldCv.ContentDocumentId);

   contentDocId.add(oldCv.ContentDocumentId);
  }
   for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId 
  FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : contentDocId])
  {   string cdlentityId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;
    if (cdlentityId.substring(0,3) == invKeyPrefix) {
   contDocLinkedMap.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, cdl.LinkedEntityId);
   System.debug('map ' +contDocLinkedMap);
    }
  }
   for ( ContentVersion oldCv : Trigger.old )                               
   {
    ContentVersion newCv = Trigger.newMap.get(oldCv.Id);
     if(oldCv.FileType=='SNOTE')
   {
   if ( oldCv.Title != newCv.Title || oldCv.Description != 
newCv.Description){
    newCv.addError('You do not have permission to edit this record.');    
  }
 }
}}
```

Comment: Your [previous version](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254825/create-notescontent-documents-preventing-the-edit-and-delete-on-notes) on `ContentDocument` had logic to do this. It wasn't perfect, but it was a start. Why not work from there?

Comment: i tried the same way, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code accumulating `ContentDocument` Ids is incorrect. It accumulates `ContentVersion` Ids.

```
for ( ContentVersion oldCv : Trigger.old )
{
    system.debug(oldCv.ContentDocumentId);
   contentDocId.add(oldCv.Id);
}
```

You debug the correct Id, but add the wrong one to the Set. As a result, your query

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : contentDocId
```

returns nothing.

You're also not using the data you accumulate. Your final `for` loop just adds an error on every `ContentVersion` in the trigger set. You need to actually write the logic to filter by linked record type.

I'm not entirely certain of the exact sequence of trigger events that takes place when a Note's content is updated. I suspect you will find you actually need to be running `after insert`, not `before update`, and come up with some logic to allow the initial insert of the first version to go through. As I mentioned on your previous question, *you will need to do some experimenting* to get this right.

Comment: i have corrected those, but note able to create the note also after the changes.